# Validate input field by selection

Tags: angular, validation, select, input, angular-abstract-control

I have a form with selection `sex` and 1 input field `nationalId`, I want to validate ID by sex, like: if user select male, the 12 digit should be odd - and be even for female.

My code:

```
nationalIdValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      let nationalId = control.get('nationalId')!;
      let sex = control.get('sexId');
      if (!nationalId || !sex || !nationalId.value || !sex.value)
        return null;

      let err = { 'nationalId not valid': { 'id': nationalId?.value, 'sex': sex?.value } }
      return (nationalId[14]?.value == sex?.value) ? err : null;
      // return nationalId ? {forbiddenName: {value: control.value}} : null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: my TS                nationalIdValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      let nationalId = control.get('nationalId')!;
      let sex=control.get('sexId');
      if(!nationalId || !sex ||!nationalId.value ||!sex.value)
      return null;


      let err={'nationalId not valid':{'id':nationalId?.value,'sex':sex?.value}}
      return (nationalId[14]?.value==sex?.value) ? err : null;
      //return nationalId ? {forbiddenName: {value: control.value}} : null;
    };
  }

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You don't have to use comment part like this. Edit your code instead and use code format. it's important to think about the people who read you.